# php recursive function doesn't go into itself

Tags: php, laravel, recursion

I wrote a recursive function in order to echo a nested list. In fact it's a helper function in laravel that get a collection of nested items and supposed to go through it and print all items' name.
But when I using it in view, just the first level of items is printed.
It seems to doesn't execute itself at `items_list($item->children());`.

```
function items_list($items)
{
    foreach($items as $item) {

        if(!$item->hasChild())
        {
            echo "
                <li>
                    ".$item->id.".".$item->name."
                </li>
            ";
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<li>".
            $item->id.".".$item->name
            ."<ul>";
            items_list($item->children());
            echo "</ul></li>";
        }
    }
}
```

here is the collection of items:

```
| id | parent_id | name                |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |      NULL | Dr. Shany Braun Jr. |
|  2 |      NULL | Lily Jerde          |
|  3 |      NULL | Dr. Herbert Kunze   |
|  4 |         1 | Ms. Shanie Skiles   |
|  5 |         1 | Dr. Anissa Kunze    |
|  6 |         2 | Maybelle Sawayn     |
|  7 |         3 | Cassie Trantow Jr.  |
|  8 |         5 | Gussie Smith        |
|  9 |         5 | Carol Mueller       |
| 10 |         7 | Shany Bayer         |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

edit:
The input of function is in fact a collection of an eloquent model that has retrieved from database I have printed above.
And here is the model:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'people';

    function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class,'parent_id');
    }

    static function first_level()
    {
        return self::all()->where('parent_id', NULL);
    }

    function hasChild()
    {
        return ($this->children() ? TRUE : FALSE);
    }
}
```

I have tested each function of this class and they work ‌properly.
and here is controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        $people = Person::first_level();
        items_list($people);
    }
}
```

and this is the output:

1.Dr. Shany Braun Jr.

2.Lily Jerde

3.Dr. Herbert Kunze

Comment: Have you checked that `$item->hasChild()` actually works? Obviously we don't know what's in $items or what that code looks like, so it's hard to say what might be going on precisely.

Comment: Please provide a minimal data set to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: It is unclear what your actual object structure is. The data you posted only shows a flat table, maybe content of a relational database table. But those are neither objects not a hierarchy, _unless you created all that, which you did not tell us anything about..._

Comment: Please show us the actual structure or an example of a structure and the desired output

Comment: I'm afraid " return null" breaks function before finishing. Remove that and see where it goes.

Comment: I provide more information. How can I reopen the question?

Comment: @adroit re-opening requires votes from people with the [necessary privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Be patient.

Comment: Anyway while you've provided some more code, you still haven't provided the basic debugging information that I asked for. e.g. can you confirm whether `$item->hasChild()` actually returns the expected result? If not, then dig deeper - does `$this->children()` within it work? Does the `hasMany` within the children function return what you expected? I'm not familiar with Eloquent but we need to at least establish whether those functions are doing what you expected. Please add some basic logging/variable-dumping so you can trace your code and the variable values.

Comment: The basic logic of the items_list function seems ok so I'd guess the issue is more likely to be somewhere in the Person class.